# Java MySql HashMap to save 3 values

Tags: java, mysql

Hy! I am working on my Java MySql app, and I need to save data about meals that are stored on my database on server, so I can later display it in combobox. User will choose what meal he wants in combo-box and when he presses "confirm" button, it will execute query about his order.
So basiclly, each meal (row) in my server database table consists of id_category (id_kategorija), id_meal (id_jela), name_of_meal (naziv_jela). Should I use HashMap for this ? If it's possible to do, how to save all that data in one Hash-Map so I can later easily make query by using that HashMap ?

Here is picture of my database table for meals:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
String queryZaJela;
Map <Integer,String>PopisJela = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
try {

        queryZaJela="SELECT id_kategorija, naziv_hrane FROM `naziv_jela`";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
                + "localhost:3306/room_service", "root", "");
        Statement Stat = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet Rez = Stat.executeQuery(queryZaJela);

        while (Rez.next()) { 

            PopisJela.put(Rez.getInt("id_kategorija"), Rez.getString("naziv_hrane") );
        } 
        PopisJela.put(0,"Select");

            Rez.close();
            Stat.close();
            con.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: A combo box needs a list of items to display. A HashMap is a dictionary (one value per key). Why don't you use a List instead, since this is what a combobox needs? Also, respect the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to have a small class to save all 3 values from database and to put the objects to that class against the `id_jela` or `id_kategorija` according to your query in future.

```
public class mealStruct {
  public int id_kategorija;
  public int id_jela;
  public string naziv_hrane;
}
```

and when you read data from database, make an object to mealStruct class and put it in the map against the id of your need.

```
//here is the HashMap of id_kategorija/id_jela and mealStruct. 
//Keep filling hashMap with id and the object. when the user selects a meal from combo,
//get the id and access the object from mealStruct and get all 3 values to use in query.
<Integer,String>PopisJela = new HashMap<Integer, mealStruct>();
```